# while exporting to the csv file time is showing based on 24

Tags: php

I have a php projec and here i need to export some data from database to the csv. My data contain "Time " and the value is "`7.00 PM`". But when i export this on cssv it's showing "`19.00`". But i want to show "`7.00 PM`"
Here is some portion of the Code

```
$out  .= '"'.$val['first_name'].'",';
$out  .= '"'.$val['second_name'].'",';
$out  .= '"'.$val['pgm_time'].'",';
$f = fopen ('registered_users.csv','w');

// Put all values from $out to export.csv. 
fputs($f, $out);
fclose($f);

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="registered_users.csv"');
readfile('registered_users.csv');
```

I have just output all these value, then it's shows correct time (7.00 Pm). but after exporting it shows 19.0 . Also my database contains teh correct value (7.00 Pm)
I have checked this in different system. In some system it's OK. But in some it's shows 19.00.. May be the version of the Microsoft or may be any inner setting of the editor. I don't know why this happen ?

I need a solution to show the time as based on 12 hrs ie 7.00 PM  in all the system (independent of editor)

Does any one know .. or any other good code .Please help me ...

Thanks

Comment: I only see a first and second name, not a time.. Please post the relevant code.

Comment: From where you get the data? is it a database or another resource ? Please post complete code

Answer (score 1):

### Look in the right place

> May be the version of the Microsoft or may be any inner setting of the editor

If you open your file in noteapad, or some other text editor - you're going to see the actual stored text, which will (probably) be "7.00 PM". If this is not the case please, please amend the question showing a reproducible bit of code to generate a csv file with "the problem".

If you open the file in Excel however, you're not *just* opening the file - it's being run through an import process. Excel will attempt to assign the right type to each column, in this case saying it's a date, and converting it appropriately. What you are describing is the user's own Excel settings for how to represent dates. This means your question has very little to do with php - and is all about how excel reads csv files.

### Forcing "show as text" for csv files in excel

It's unclear why you want to do this (knowing why, may lead to a different suggestion), but if you prefix the field value with a single quote `'` this will force excel to represent the cell value as text, rather than automatically determining the cell/column type:

```
$out  .= '"\''.$val['pgm_time'].'",';
```

i.e. obtaining:

```
"foo","bar","'7.00 PM"
```

This will likely make the csv file problematic or useless to any other process that needs to read it

Comment: It's clear that not the version problem. it's the inner settings of the excel file ..

Comment: ? you don't have an excel file

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to force that? That's one of those things that are supposed to be left to whatever is displaying the data. In fact, even if you were to output data in 12h format, opening the CSV in Excel or the like might just reformat it to 24h format anyway. It's best to leave time data in whatever format it comes in.